# CoreData Fetch creates String from Double

Tags: ios, core-data

I am querying HealthKit and saving the entries to CoreData: Here is my Fetch Request:

```
func queryCoreDataData () -> NSArray {
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "HKActiveEnergyBurned")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var hkActiveEnergyBurned = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as [HKActiveEnergyBurned]
var activeEnergyBurnedData = (hkActiveEnergyBurned as NSArray).valueForKey("activeEnergyBurned_data") as NSArray  
println("CoreData Fetch activeEnergyBurnedData: \(activeEnergyBurnedData)")

return activeEnergyBurnedData
}
```

I print each entry to the console.  The console shows this:

```
Saving to CoreData:
CD save activeEnergyBurned: 740.0
CD save activeEnergyBurned: 725.0
CD save activeEnergyBurned: 4.0
CD save activeEnergyBurned: 152.0
CD save activeEnergyBurned: 459.0
```

When I later Fetch the data some of the entries have become Strings!

```
CoreData Fetch activeEnergyBurnedData: (
"739.9999999999999",
    725,
    4,
    152,
    "459.0000000000001"
)
```

Here is a picture of my CoreData Model

[image: CoreData Model]

and the NSManaged Object:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class HKActiveEnergyBurned: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var activeEnergyBurned_data: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var activeEnergyBurned_date: NSDate

}
```

I tried to google this, but nothing comes up.  Maybe I am asking the wrong question.  **Does anyone know why this happen and how I can make sure that the values stay as double?**  (You may notice that the NSManaged Object comes up as NSNumber, I am not sure why that happens either). 
 Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you !

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that logs the fetched data.

Comment: Can it have something to do with the use of comma versus full stop in specifying doubles.  The issue seem to happen when the data from HealthKit is either a number with a decimal, or the sum total (ex active calories) of several entries throughout the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers are printing surrounded by quotes when they contain a decimal point, but they are still stored as numbers. You can reproduce this trivially:

```
let array = [ 739.9, 725 ] as NSArray
println("\(array)")
```

Output:

```
(
    "739.9",
    725
)
```

String interpolation uses the `description` method (in this case), and this is just the way `-[NSArray description]` works. It's not a bug. If you don't like it, you'll have to convert the array to a string “manually” instead of relying on `description`.

Comment: Why does it only happen when the numbers contain a decimal point and not when they don't?

Comment: It happens when the number contains any non-digit. You can reproduce it with `-1` or `1e22` also. As for why it's implemented that way, I can't say.

Comment: Ok Thank you, well you are both right.  Although I would like to give the points to Max K since he was first, your example made it slightly more informative.  I also used the example to understand a problem that stemmed from this issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The type of the `activeEnergyBurned_data` is `NSNumber` however when you print it to console the [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method is called. This method is needed to provide textual representation of the object. So that is why you see numbers printed in quotes. This method is inherited from `NSObject` protocol so that any object has a chance to provide textual representation for debugging or logging, etc.